# How to know webjars paths in Spring Boot. How to get paths of all available files in webjars

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, jar, webjars

Many questions on SO refer to invalid paths for various resorces located in Spring-Boot webjars. Currently I have a problem with tether but 
I do not want to put another one specifically about tether's webjar files/paths, so want to ask:

- Is there any easy way of seeing all contents available through @{/webjars /NAME}?
- What is the easiest to debug invalid 404 webjar path in Spring Boot?
- How can I see mappings of all that a webjar contains?

Cheers

PS: jquery, bootstrap work fine for me. My tether webjar does not.

```
<script th:src="@{/webjars/tether/1.4.3/js/tether.min.js}" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Silly me.

Look **PROPERLY** :D into the jar file,

Or even easier - look it up on the http://www.webjars.org webpage.
If you click link under "files" you will be able to see all jar contents, e.g:

https://www.webjars.org/listfiles/d3js/4.10.2

Comment: Yeah, the easier way is to look into the jar file for the path to your dependecy :)